# How to check if displayMessage() is no longer on screen

Tags: java

I made my `displayMessage()` clickable this way (thanks stackoverflow!):

```
public class Tray {
    private static class ShowMessageListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            trayIcon.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (openBrowser == 1) {

                        Desktop desktop = Desktop.isDesktopSupported() ? Desktop
                                .getDesktop() : null;
                        if (desktop != null
                                && desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
                            try {
                                desktop.browse(URI.create(link));
                            } catch (Exception e2) {
                                LogError.get(e2);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    openBrowser = 0;
                }
            });
            trayIcon.displayMessage("Finished", link,
                    TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
        }
    } //ShowMessageListener class end
invisibleItem.addActionListener(new ShowMessageListener());
}
```

and I'm dispatching event to show the message:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(new ActionEvent(Tray.invisibleItem, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "asd", 1, 0));
```

Everything works great, the message is clickable. It was perfect until I realized that `ActionListener` is listening to `TrayIcon` too. If the user doesn't click on the message, `TrayIcon` will take the event on the next click and open the website.

Here's my question: how can I check if `displayMessage()` is gone?

Comment: maybe there is a time for showing message (check), you need to check the time, or implicitly remove the message is howing and set the openBroswer to false

Comment: I thought about timer (i.e. 5 seconds and then dismiss notification - but how?). Also user can keep mouse over the message - it won't dismiss.

Comment: okay add a mouseMotionListener to the tryIcon, and after showing the message run a thread that counts to 5, then set openBrowser to false IF AND IF user is not keeping in message that you can achieve it with mouse motion listener you added

Comment: It may be a solution. I'm going to try it tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Did that solution work for you? (I'd like to know before I go through the effort of implementing it)